# Allow some letters in reg expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next regExp:

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\&()',_\-]+$");
```

I want to allow `@`

so I tried:

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\&()',_\-@]+$");
```

but there was an exception:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s&()',_-@]+$/: Range out of order in character class`

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qv5syoev/

can someone knows why this regex is invalid?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Should be no regex error using `@` in the class, must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such range `_-@` Better put the escape back on the `\-` range operator,
or you can put the operator at the beginning or end of the class, where it is treated as a literal.

Ok, since its double quoted, you have to escape it twice. `\\-` Once for the lang parser the other for the regex parser.

Comment: Thank you! can I write: "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\&()',_\-]+$+\@"   ?

Comment: or you want me to write: "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\&()',_@\-]+$" ?

Comment: Better make it `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\&()',_\\-@]+$"`

Comment: Should have used the regex literal instead. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\&()',_\-@]+$/`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, what is the difference between what you suggested and the regular expresion of sln?

Comment: @ErezShmiel In regex literals you don't need to "double-escape" special characters.